# WxPython and ShowMeDo tutorial

Tags: python, wxpython

I was working through the third video in this tutorial series in my effort to learn WxPython. I typed the code as in the video but an error is still returned. I am guessing this has something to do with the WxPython or Python version used. He is using Python 2.4, I am using 2.7.5 and I don't know what WxPython version he is using but I am using 3.0.0.

This is the code:

```
import wx

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,id,title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,wx.ID_ANY,title,size = (400,200), style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE | wx.NO_FULL_REPAINT_ON_RESIZE
        self.control = wx.TextCtrl(self,1,style = wx.TE_MULTILINE)
        self.Show(True)

app = wx.PySimpleApp()
frame = MainWindow(None,-1,"Small Editor")
app.MainLoop()
```

Invalid syntax is returned for `self.control` but I don't know why.

Any help is appreciated,

Fluffy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're missing the final enclosing parenthesis on the line directly above.

Generally speaking, syntax errors are typically due to misspellings, missing characters, or other such mistakes, and can either be found on the line indicated by the stacktrace or the line directly above.

Once the parenthesis is added, the below code runs for me:

```
import wx

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,id,title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,wx.ID_ANY,title,size = (400,200), style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE | wx.NO_FULL_REPAINT_ON_RESIZE)
        self.control = wx.TextCtrl(self,1,style = wx.TE_MULTILINE)
        self.Show(True)

app = wx.PySimpleApp()
frame = MainWindow(None,-1,"Small Editor")
app.MainLoop()
```